# roots of concave functions

Tags: functional-analysis

How can we show that the function $$ f(x):= x(x^{p-2}+1-p)-c(x^{p-2}+1+p) \qquad (0 < x < (p-1)^{\frac{1}{p-2}} )$$ which in it $ 1<p<2 $ and $ c=(2(p-1))^{\frac{1}{p-2}}$, has no root? We know this function is strictly concave.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? As it stand, this is just a problem statement, which is generally not received well.

Comment: Our problem is that I couldn't find the maximum point of it in order to showing that the function is negative in this point and then according to concativity  we can conclude that it hasn't any root. Off course there is a direct way. I'm trying to show that the function is negative.

Comment: Do you *know* that it has no roots, or do you want to know *whether* it has no roots? Also, how do you know the function is strictly concave?

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is strictly concave. In special case we observed that it has no root.